# What is this type of interaction/component called?

Tags: usability, design-patterns, lists, input-fields, multi-selection

When a user fills out some input fields and adds it as an entry to an existing list. Usually there's a way to edit/delete these entries as well.

[image: Screenshot from YNAB budgeting app]

[image: Screenshot from Google Calendar]

Comment: Delete buttons?

Comment: Hmmm... I've answered, but not sure what exactly we should be looking at? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Are you asking 1) what is it call when you edit/delete 2) what is it called when you add to a list 3) what is it called when you can edit a table row in place?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not  UX related

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you show is called *row editor* or *[row editing plugin](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/grid/row-editing.html)*:

[image: A screenshot of a row editor]

Not to be confused with inline editors:

[image: A table with an inline editor on one of the fields]

which only allow to edit one field at a time

Comment: Row Editor! That is clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a pretty loose question, but I think I know what you're after ...*

### In-line or contextual controls

They are really just buttons, but they apply to minor interface elements at the local level. As you point out in your examples, this pattern is most often used in data-heavy, highly editable views. Since the number of editable elements can be relatively numerous, these controls are often masked until either selection or hover.

Answer (score 1):

CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) is a common shorthand for the 4 basic abilities of such a list. The examples you posted are essentially just "add new" functions.

Answer (score 0):

These are regular textboxes or combo box that allow you to edit an entry, but to do that you will need some code either via JavaScript or PHP or similar. The code will enable edit mode on the entries.

Answer (score 0):

As the system is asking the user to enter information this pattern looks like the 'Fill in the blanks' pattern as shown on the UIPatterns.com website. http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/FillInTheBlanks